# Unable to set read and write databases for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am experimenting with AWS Aurora but for some reason, I'm unable to connect to both databases as mentioned in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html.

For example, my secrets file looks very similar to this:

```
  9 development:
 10   primary:
 11     host: my-write-db.rds.amazonaws.com
 12     username: [username]
 13     password: [pw]
 14     database: [db]
 15   primary_replica:
 16     host: my-ro-replica.rds.amazonaws.com
 17     username: [username]
 18     password: [pw]
 19     database: [db]
 20     replica: true
```

However, when I go to fire up browser to navigate to the login page, I receive the following error message:

[image]

Further down in the article suggests editing the `app/models/application_record.rb` file, but doing that only causes the following error when trying to start the webrick server:

```
ubuntu@d5537024b8e1:~/myapp$ rails s --binding 0.0.0.0 -p 80                                                         
=> Booting Puma                                                                                                       
=> Rails 7.0.2.4 application starting in development                                                               
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options                                                                  
Exiting                                                                                                                    
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.4/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:177:in `resolve_symbol_connection': The `primary_replica` database is not configured for the `development`
 environment. (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Available database configurations are:                                                                                   
                                                                                                                   
  default                                                                                                           
production                                                                                                            
development
```

I feel like I'm missing something that I think is probably simple. Is this only supported for the production environment perhaps?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the database is incorrectly exited.
Try:

```bash
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
```